# Create my own API

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I use in my force.com application Apex Classes, and many of them have the same structure, I want to make an API to reuse it after.

For exaple, these are two classes :

```
//first class

public class insererActAct{

public List<Activites_actuelles__c> accts {get; set;}

public insererActAct(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    accts = new List<Activites_actuelles__c>();
    accts.add(new Activites_actuelles__c());
}

public void addrow(){
    accts.add(new Activites_actuelles__c());

}

public PageReference deleteRow(){
   if (accts.size()>1)
   {
      accts.remove(accts.size()-1);
   }
   return null;
}

public PageReference save()
{
    insert accts;
    Assure__c theParent = new Assure__c(id=accts[0].Activites_actuelles__c);
    PageReference acctPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(theParent).view();
    acctPage.setRedirect(true);
    return acctPage;
}
}

//second class

public class insererEnfants{

public List<Enfants__c> accts {get; set;}

public insererEnfants(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    accts = new List<Enfants__c>();
    accts.add(new Enfants__c());
}

public void addrow(){
    accts.add(new Enfants__c());

}

public PageReference deleteRow(){
   if (accts.size()>1)
   {
      accts.remove(accts.size()-1);
   }
   return null;
}

public PageReference save()
{
    insert accts;
    Assure__c theParent = new Assure__c(id=accts[0].Parent__c);
    PageReference acctPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(theParent).view();
    acctPage.setRedirect(true);
    return acctPage;
}
}
```

Can any one tell me it is possible or not, if yes, how can I do this, please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean you want to write code that works for different kinds of objects, rather than stating the type of object in the code?

It is possible to do this, by declaring your sObject variables with the sObject type, e.g, instead of

```
public List<Activites_actuelles__c> accts {get; set;}
```

you would put

```
public List<sObject> sObjects{get; set;}
```

and by referencing fields using get and put, e.g. instead of

```
Account theAccount = new Account();
theAccount.name = 'Fred';
```

you would put

```
sObject theSObject = new SObject();
theSObject.put('name', 'Fred');
```

I've not tried using code like this in a controller extension, but in theory since you can pass in any standard controller you ought to be OK.

You will need to think about how to create the parent object inside the save method, because you will need to pass in what type you want to create. It's quite complicated but it is possible to take in a string representing the object type (e.g. 'Account') and create a new object of that type:

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').newSObject()
```

will get you a new Account. So you could replace 'Account' with any type passed in as a parameter.

For more information look up Dynamic Apex, Dynamic SOQL and Dynamic DML in the documentation.

A word of warning: Passing around object types and field names as strings means that the compiler will not know those types are mentioned in the code. So if you try and delete a custom object or rename a field, salesforce will not warn you that the object or field is in use and will allow you to do the deletion.

Another word of warning: Although this allows code reuse and that is a benefit, you may find it is not worth it. I avoid writing dynamic apex unless I absolutely have to. It is far more complex than ordinary apex and it is therefore difficult to debug and maitain, especially if someone other than yourself has to maintain it.

Comment: I have an other question, how can I insert the value of the master relationship field in the child automatically, because I have one parent for every child ?

Comment: you might be able to do complicated things with getDescribe() to find out what kind of object the parent is (not sure if possible or not), but I think it would be easier to keep the object type names in custom settings (as strings).

Comment: Thanks for response, but I have a VF inputField `<apex:inputField value="{!Enfants__c.Parent__c}"/>` in witch I have to insert the value every time, but this value is unique, the parent name, how can I pass and insert this value (parent name) automatically, this is my question.